# Symfony2 FOSRest set value to null

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

In a web application built with Symfony2, I need to be able to send `null` values as part of a `PUT` or `PATCH` request to an FOSRestBundle endpoint.
e.g. `{ "available": null }`. The database field is a `nullable` `boolean` type which is set by Doctrine. So in effect, the value needs to be able to be `1, 0 or null` (i.e. unknown). Sending a `null` value seems to be ignored though. This could be an issue with either Symfony2 forms or with FOSRest. I have tried adding `empty_value => null` and `empty_data => null` to the form, but nothing seems to work. Any idea if there is a setting which allows accepting `null` as an option?

Comment: Seems like it is automatically converting null to false...

Comment: Looks like it is partly to do with the form applying a transformer by default (`Booleantostringtransformer`). I tried turning it off with `"inherit_data" => true`, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Any suggestions on overriding and writing own data transformer would be welcome! (I've tried but didn't seem to work either)

Comment: After more digging, all I really think I need to do is know how to remove a view transformer (as I'm applying my own to a custom form type and transformer, but the BooleanToString transformer is still getting applied!!)

Answer (score 4):

Boolean is either true or false normally, how can you determine that it was unchecked because it was null or unchecked because it was false, either way it is false. So if you want 3 choices better use choice field not checkbox, with  (Choose, Yes, No) with values (null, 1, 0).

You can check this but i don't think it will help much https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/10364

Comment: Thanks for the info, am not actually using a checkbox though, it is just a database boolean field which is updated by submitted JSON data (so needs to be able to be true, false or null)! It is only a problem when using Symfony forms, not when not!

Comment: @timhc22 what Nawfal said is actually true. It is a long standing bug in Symfony forms. Since the doctrine type is "boolean", the form type is guessed to be a checkbox field; this means that when used in a REST application it won't work the way you expect, especially for PATCH method. The easy way is to use a "choice" field with [0, 1] values and "required => false" option. If you rather prefer pure true and false values, you'll probably need a custom ChoiceInterface class, as explained in the official docs.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set in your config:

```
fos_rest:
    serializer:
        serialize_null: true
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try do a virtual property sending a string "0","1" or "null" and expose as the name of your other property.

Answer (score 1):

Set Default value to NULL while DB design and ignore the field while insertion using query , It will be inserted NULL automatically.

Comment: you mean remove `->add('myBooleanField')` from the form builder?

Comment: Yes ,  if its value is null

Comment: but it needs to be true, false or null, and it won't get set at all if it isn't there!

Comment: its fine then , you dont need to do anything , Just alter table and Set Default value to NULL  And try again.